# Does this follow a Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability

I buy a lightbulb from a hardware store and D measures its lifespan. D follows an exponential distribution with $\lambda = \dfrac1{10}$  Let X measure the number of days it will take me to realize the lightbulb has died.

What distribution does X follow?

Comment: Is it fair to say $P(X=k) = P(k-1 < D \leq k)$? If so, can you find the distribution of $X$ using that knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not Poisson; it's geometric. Since $X\ge k$ iff $D>k-1$, $X=k$ iff $k-1<D\le k$, which has probability $q^{k-1}(1-q)$ with $q:=e^{-\lambda}$.

Comment: @jdoe Yes, that's it.